# Why do i keep getting an TemplateSyntaxError on line 4

Tags: html, django

i keep getting error on line 4 onle when i add the last h1 block with its block content and endblock
here is the error
TemplateSyntaxError at /mySecondPage
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

```
{% extends "index.html" %} {% block title %}My Second Page{% endblock %} {%
block content %}
<h1>Hello, world! Django First Page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

i dont know how to ifx it can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

You should not span template tags over multiple lines, the parser (currently) can not handle this, so:

```
{% extends "index.html" %} {% block title %}My Second Page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello, world! Django First Page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

likely it might be better, just for aesthetic purposes to use separate lines per block:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block title %}My Second Page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello, world! Django First Page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```